# My Spring Security app doesn't accept "Newly uploaded Images" to be accessed from the resource folder

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application with security enabled. This is my security configuration file:

```java
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
       .ignoring()
           .antMatchers("/resources/**"); 
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login", 
              "/api/user/register",
              "/api/password/forgot_password", 
              "/api/password/reset_password",
              "/resources/**", 
              "/api/event/",
              "/api/photography/files/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers( "/assets/img/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    httpSecurity
        .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

When I try to access an image from `/resource/static/assets/img/xxx.png` it works. but only for existing images. When I run the application and then upload an image. I get `Unauthorized error 401`.

Comment: Where did you save the uploaded files? The existiing files are on your class path in your JAR file. Where are your uploaded files?

Comment: i solved it with a middleware resource folder in the same dir as the frontend and backend